# Is there a way to configure IIS logs to retrieve the user details from forms authentication?

Tags: iis, forms, forms-authentication

I am trying to analyse the IIS log and would like to look at the broken down by user.  I can't do this at the moment because I am using Forms Authentication and IIS is logging everyone as anonymous, which obviously is expected.

Is there a way to configure IIS to retrieve the user details from Forms Authentication?

Comment: I guess this could belong on serverfault but I came to this problem while programming so I immediately thought it should be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, what you want cannot be achieved as form authentication is designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you'd have to put some sort of identifier in the URL Query String for each page call.